How to open Canon printer driver setup window in Ubuntu 20.04
About two years ago I installed the Canon MG2522 printer on Ubuntu 20.04 using the Michael Gruz ppa repository.  It has worked very well since then.
Today I need to increase the print intensity of a page I am printing.  According to Canon, I do that in the Printer Driver Setup Window (see, e.g., https://ij.manual.canon/ij/webmanual/PrinterDriver/W/MG2500%20series/1.0/EN/PPG/dg-c_opendriver.html) but that page is about Windows.
I would like to open the same window in Ubuntu, or find the correct command to set print intensity.  There are some useful commands at https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2015/01/lpadmin-examples/ but not print intensity.
The printer information is:
lpstat -v
device for MG2500-series: usb://Canon/MG2500%20series?serial=6373FE&interface=1
device for PDF: cups-pdf:/
Thanks very much for any help.

Does the Print Settings dialog help you? If it is not in your menu system try the command system-config-printer. Under the "printer/properties" headings I have a lot of choices for configuring the printer.

Thanks, Organic Marble.  I used system-config-printer and it opened the print dialog.  There are lots of settings there.  That should solve my problem.
